# Symfony2/Doctrine2 caching stuff to avoid queries

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

Background: I have a fairly big table (2000 rows, 10 columns) full of small int (0,1,2 only).
Given an entity and a field of that entity, depending on the values of the 10 columns I get the information if I want to display and or make required that field of that entity when I render the form.
Instead of querying the DB for each field, every time I have my ->add in the form builder, I'd like to cache the whole table "somewhere" in server's memory.

How can I do that? Is it necessary that each user "loads" the table, or can it be done once for all of the users and each user simply reads server's RAM?

That table almost never changes. Still I need to be able to upload an updated version of it every once in a while (veeery seldom).

Thank you!

SN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is use `useResultCache` method.

`Doctrine` uses cache driver set in `Symfony` configuration, so when you write `queryBuilder` which is fetching data from your table just tell `Doctrine` you want result to be cached (for how long and under what key is optional):

```
class YourEntityRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function getAllRowsCached()
    {
        $cachedResult = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->getQuery()
            ->useResultCache(true, 3600, 'cache_key')
            ->getArrayResult();

        return $cachedResult;
    }

}
```

Cache is common for all users so first user will query DB, second will use data from cache. Also note, that by default in `dev` environment cache is disabled.

Check [this blog entry](http://blog.alterphp.com/2014/05/doctrine2-optimization-with-apc-cache.html) for more detailed info

Comment: This is fantastic...too easy to be true :). Thank you!